# Creating a loop using Python (to simulate a "goto" like solution)

Tags: python, json, loops, if-statement

Here is my approach to simulate a goto sequence. Is there a more eloquent way?

PS: the idea with storing the variable in a class variable was just for fun (because of the .(format()) accessing story.

```
n=0
while n==0:
    print("Whats your height?")
    height=input()
    print("Whats your age?")
    age=input()

    class loop:
        h=height
        a=age

    print("Your height is {answer.h}".format(answer=loop()))
    print("Would you like to continue?")
    answer=input()
    if answer=="yes":
        ++n
        print("alright ONE MORE TIME!")
    else:
        print("see you")
```

Comment: damnit i forgot the "break" after "..see you" xD

Comment: What are you trying to do? What about this needs a goto?

Comment: actually its not about to become a "goto", since im new in python btw. in programming i remembered from c(i think) a thing called goto. But after a lot of research i discovered that goto is..crap(summary). so my curiosity is more like "is there a way to pull the code above in a more smart way down

Comment: If you forgot something, you can [edit] your question to add it.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self,name, height, age):
        self.name = name
        self.height = height
        self.age = age

while True:
    name = input("What's your name?\n")
    height = input("What's your height?\n")
    age = input("What's your age?\n")

    user = Person(name, height, age)

    print(f"\nHello {(user.name).title()}, your height is {user.height} and you are" \
          f" {user.age} years old!")

    answer = input("\nWould you like to continue?('yes' or 'no')\n")

    if answer == 'yes':
        print("alright ONE MORE TIME!")
        continue
    else:
        print("See you!")
        break
```

This is how I would go about this, although there is no reason to have a class here for what you are trying to accomplish, but since you had it in there I'm assuming you were using it as practice, so I threw in a class here as well.

**Edit**

Ah you mentioned the `class` was for fun, not claiming I used `class` in the best fashion here but it's an improvement for the way you attempted, would definitely look over proper utilization of `class`.

Comment: Your welcome, but you are dong me a service as well! Helping others is a good way to learn, since you need to try to get a even better understanding to explain to someone else. Take time on here to look around and attempt to solve/learn from others questions, it helps.